# When to use connection pooling or single connection?

Tags: database, database-connection

Hypothetical scenario:

I have a database server that has significantly more RAM/CPU than could possibly be used in its current system. Connecting an application server to it, would I get better preformance using pooling to use multiple connections that each have smaller executions, or a single connection with a larger execution?

More importantly, why? I'm having trouble finding any reference material to pull me one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always vote for connection pooling for a couple of reasons.

- the pool layer will deal with failures and grabbing a working connection when you need it
- you can service multiple requests concurrently by using different connections at the same time.  a single connection will often block and queue up requests to the db
- establishing a connection to a db is expensive - pools can do this up front and in the background as needed

There's also a handy discussion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457287/what-is-the-benefit-of-connection-and-statement-pooling).

Comment: But if the application server always remained connected to the database server wouldn't the benefits of connecting mostly disappear?

Comment: how can you guarantee there are no network hiccups?  Also, it still doesn't solve the concurrent request issue.