# benefit of multiple jdbc database connection over single database connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

My first Approach:
  I am developing a project where i am using Mysql with JDBC. What I am doing, I have fixed number of query. So i am creating a database connection and over same connection I am creating map of preparedstatement for all query. When i have to execute any query, I am taking preparedstatemtn from Map, executing and not closing preparedstatement after completing query execution. To support from multiple thread applying lock on preparedstatement.

Another Approach:

I can create a database connection pool. when i need to execute query, i shall retrieve a connection from pool, create statement/preparedstatement on it, execute and close.

i am confused which approach will be more effiecient? as my environment is multi threaded

Comment: AFAIK..your another approach sounds familiar and widely accepted!!

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Database connection pools are standard, there are a lot of implementations (which sometimes also provide statement pooling); there is no need to reinvent the wheel and implement it yourself.

Comment: Well the DB Connection Pool is the best one

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457287/what-is-the-benefit-of-connection-and-statement-pooling/457303#457303 ?